# Close InfoWindow on iOS

Tags: google-maps, ionic3, infowindow

In an Ionic app on iOS I load JS Google Maps. The problem is that the Infowindow does not want to close. The Infowindows are already present on GMaps so its not an incorrect implementation. They close on the browser on desktop but not on iOS.